# Python connect_ex does not work while port scanning

Tags: python

I was trying to test few things on server , remotely seems that nmap and telnet are working but my below script for port scanning doesn't work.

NOTE:- its pretty basic in port scanning and also i know we can have counter measures but its should also block nmap etc.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
ip = ['xx.xx.xx.xx']
import socket
for i in  ip:
    print "Scanning " + i + " for open port"
    for p in xrange(1,10000):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s = sock.connect_ex((i,p))
        print p
        if s is 0:
            print str(p) + '-' +  str(s)
```

Comment: It seems to be working for me.. I can connect to port 80 on a HTTP server, and SSH port is blocked.

Comment: ok, so if port scanning is disabled on server , should nmap work ?